# Customized application in app and play stores

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, hybrid-mobile-app

I have developed a react native mobile application for Android and iOS platforms and I want to publish this app multiple times for each of my customers. It is the same application with exactly same functionalities, but each customer need to have the app with its own icon and own name.

Is this possilbe ? please can you share with me app and play stores rules about that.

Regards,

Omar.

Comment: Apple has been refusing "white labelled" apps lately; See https://whova.com/blog/no-more-white-label-event-apps-says-apple/ and https://apptooltester.com/app-store-rejecting-app-maker-apps-guideline-4-2-6/ and App Store guide 4.2.6

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Product Flavors.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

If there is a genuine need for multiple apps then that should not fall foul of Play Store policies. For example, some online supermarkets use the same app re-branded for each company.

Comment: i have a same question. but in addition to this, i need to customize images, styles, and other resources per customer. any help will be appreciated

Comment: That is included in the link above: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourceset-build

Comment: Thanks for the reply. in my react-native project resources are common between android and ios version. is there any other solution to prevent duplicates? my resources includes javascript files, styles, images per customer. i don't know how to do this in the react-native for both android and ios version.

Comment: You should open your own question to get a wider audience who have experience in both Android and IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible you have to do productFlavors

**Step 1 :**

```
signingConfigs {
        client1{
            storeFile file("keystore")
            storePassword "secret"
            keyAlias "aliasForFlavor1"
            keyPassword "secretFlavor1"
        }

        client2{
            storeFile file("keystore")
            storePassword "secret"
            keyAlias "aliasForFlavor2"
            keyPassword "secretFlavor2"
        }......
    }

    productFlavors {
        def signingConfigsClient1 = signingConfigs.client1
        def signingConfigsClent2 = signingConfigs.client2
        client1{
            applicationIdSuffix ".client1"
            signingConfig signingConfigsClient1
        }
       client2{
            applicationIdSuffix ".client2"
            signingConfig signingConfigsClient2
        }.....
}
```

**Step 2 :** Create a drawable/strings.xml.... folder

```
        SRC--> clent1 --> drawable
        SRC--> clent2 --> drawable......
```

For more Info follow this URL

http://santhoshkumarsrs.blogspot.in/2017/03/how-to-deal-with-product-flavors-in.html